# OS X 10.6SDK compatible with 10.5 leopard system __ZNKSt13bad_exception4whatEV

Tags: macos, boost, compilation, compatibility

My project is compiled with 10.6SDK and selected 10.5 as Deployment Target. When I run the binary in 10.5 leopard system it gives me

Symbol not found: __ZNKSt13bad_exception4whatEV

Referenced from: ......
Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib

Sometimes ago I got the same problem and I closed to use a boost header to make a solution but it was temporary solution. Why this happen? If this symbol is not in 10.5 system, why it compiles without problem?

I can't even find which library call this symbol (probably boost but where?)

Edit:

I found the guilty. thread.o compiled file call __ZNKSt13bad_exception4whatEV this symbol. I had updated boost library from 1.46 to 1.53. Before I had the same problem and I had changed:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
```

to

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
```

and the problem was gone. Now when I updated boost to 1.53, this is calling again.

I compiled boost with macports or with b2.

```
otool -L bin.v2/libs/thread/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/address-model-32_64/macosx-version-min-10.4/macosx-version-10.8/threading-multi/libboost_thread.dylib 
bin.v2/libs/thread/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/address-model-32_64/macosx-version-min-10.4/macosx-version-10.8/threading-multi/libboost_thread.dylib:
    libboost_thread.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    libboost_system.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 56.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

I still see `/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib`. That means it doesn't compatible with 10.5.

I also looked a solution for static link with libstdc++ but I cound't find it.

I am still looking a solution for it.

Edit2:

I think I give up. I don't have more time for this ridiculous situation. I don't understand why Apple don't supply a updated libstdc++ for 10.5 leopard system. There are so many problem with libstdc++ in 10.5.

The main question why Xcode did NOT tell me this binary is not compatible with 10.5 system?

Windows is much more well about backward compatibility. Now, I can even compile for xp sp3.

I use always staticaly link in Windows but in Apple this is imposible.

At this moment I have learnt that if I want to use c++11 features, I have to compile for 10.7 system. Not even for 10.6 system too. But in Professional Audio so many people use still 10.6 system. I have to wait to use c++11 because of Apple's non static link situation or Aplle's backward compatibility approach.

Yes, I am little bit angry!